# Validating jQueryUi DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I'm having a lot of trouble with a jQueryUI DatePicker.

Whenever it loses focus, the background of the TextBox turns a light shade of red (presumably indicating an invalid date).

It is doing this even when the date is valid (en-AU).

I have written the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.date').each(function () {

        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: '/Content/calendar.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });

});
```

I also looked at this page, which does not seem to work: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization
If you set the textbox on the right to English-Australian, then select a date, it is still in the US format.

I also tried adding:

```
$(this).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en-AU']);
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this problem in the past.

You need to add a javascript file for localization to work properly.

Here is a list of all the localization files: http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/i18n/ . Make sure to add it to your `<head>` and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

---

***EDIT:***

Use this link for the localization script:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

I have also provided a demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/93RGW/139/

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I even pasted the contents of the localisation file into my script. The input element still turns red upon selecting valid dates.

Comment: That gave a somewhat curious result lol - http://i167.photobucket.com/albums/u122/sixesallround/datepicker_zps8fc7bf01.png

Comment: Update. The red shading only happens in Chrome. In Firefox and IE8, the  datepicker seems to be fine.

Comment: Please use the demo i have provided and update with your code.  I will then take a look at it.

Comment: OK. I got it working at last. I had to create a whole new project and update everything to the latest via nuget (including that localisation script). Must have been something hinkey with a version mismatch in my previous attempt. Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, one other thing. To get it working in Chrome, I had to change the class attribute of the input element to something other than 'date'. Chrome will try and use it's native support for an HTML5 datepicker.